# How do you include a Typescript namespace in a test file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a `Foo.ts` file that contains the `namespace Foo { ... }` and some exported functions. I want to test the functions in this namespace using a test file right next to this one called `Foo.test.ts`.

```js
///<reference path="./Foo.ts" />
import './Foo';
console.log(typeof Foo)
```

However, when I try to run the test file using mocha, I get an error.

```
 ReferenceError: Foo is not defined
```

How do I include the typescript namespace so I can access `Foo.bar()` and other exported functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is pretty sufficient documentation on namespaces here: [Typescript Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

Your Foo.ts should look like this:

```
export namespace Foo {
 export function Bar() {
      return 'Bar';
 }
}
```

And then in the other file:

```
import * as Foo from './Foo';
console.log(typeof Foo)
```

I think you could do this to:

```
import { Foo } from './Foo';
console.log(typeof Foo)
```

Comment: I read that documentation (among dozens of other pages), but it never explained the magical mix of `export namespace Foo`  with `import { Foo } from './Foo'`

Comment: @Xeoncross I see. Anything you want to use in another file needs to be "exported" or else it won't be available in the calling file.